# Swing Dialog gradient paint Issue

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Want to paint gradient background for dialog box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't play with the root pane or layered pane.
2. Don't override paint() on a JFrame or JDialog.

If you want to do custom painting for the background then you override the paintComponent(...) method of a JPanel. You then set this panel as the content pane of your dialog.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples to get you started.

Also, Swing does not support transparent background correctly.

The basic logic for painting transparent backgrounds is:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```

Check out [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information.

So first get the gradient painting working on the custom panel using non-transparent colors. Once you understand the proper way to do the custom painting you can then worry about the transparency.

Comment: Thank you so much . I created customised JPanel which has the gradient background

Comment: I am attaching the code snippet but i dont know how to set this panel as a content pane for my jdialog. Can you please help?

Comment: I have added a code snippet to my original post . Can you please take a look . It will be really appericiated

Comment: Well you can just add it to the dialog as shown in the custom painting tutorial. Or you can use dialog.setContentPane( yourPanelHere );

Comment: You can check out the [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a working example of using a GradientPaint.

Comment: Thank you so much Camickr, So the I can see the gradient background on my JDialogs, but everytime I press the button that brings up the Dialog . It appends its content again and again making it super Long . I am attaching the image in my original post.

Comment: Don't keep adding the panel. The panel is created once when the dialog is created. And I told you transparent colors don't work properly. Read the link I provided!

Comment: Oh.. So i was declaring Mypanel p= new Mypanel(); and then adding this panel to my jdialog box. But if I dont declare the panel. It prompts with the error to declare it locally . So My customised panel and the class with dialog is in different packages, I have imported the class. But i am still not able to fix the issue . I am sorry . I am little newbie

Comment: thank you so much , I went through articles and I have successfully done it . Thanks a Ton :)